# How to create a pop up message when a button is pressed in Python 3.4.1?

Tags: python, button, python-3.x, tkinter, popup

I'm trying to create a pop up message which appears when a button is clicked. Is there any way to do using tkinter in Python 3.4.1?

Comment: that would depend on whether you just wanted a standard popup (one that tells you something or asks a simple question) or something more complicated that you can define as a popup

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import tkinter.messagebox
def onClick():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Title goes here","Message goes here")
root = tkinter.Tk()
button = tkinter.Button(root,text = "Click Me", command = onClick)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```